# T-SQL: Can I query one view for values and then query a second view only for values that don't exist in the first?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, duplicates, union

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ..Players
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ..FreeAgents

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FreeAgents](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Position] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FreeAgents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Position] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Players] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[FreeAgents] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FreeAgents] ([Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Position]) VALUES (2, N'Julian', N'Edelman', N'WideReceiver')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FreeAgents] ([Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Position]) VALUES (3, N'Dez', N'Bryant', N'WideReceiver')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FreeAgents] ([Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Position]) VALUES (4, N'Brandon', N'Jacobs', N'DefensiveEnd')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[FreeAgents] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Players] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Players] ([Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Position]) VALUES (1, N'Tom', N'Brady', N'Quarterback')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Players] ([Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Position]) VALUES (2, N'Cam', N'Newton', N'Quarterback')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Players] ([Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Position]) VALUES (3, N'Julian', N'Edelman', N'WideReceiver')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Players] OFF
GO

SELECT FirstName, LastName, Position FROM ..Players
UNION
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Position FROM ..FreeAgents
```

The code above returns five rows. This is correct.

| FirstName | LastName | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brandon | Jacobs | DefensiveEnd |
| Cam | Newton | Quarterback |
| Dez | Bryant | WideReceiver |
| Julian | Edelman | WideReceiver |
| Tom | Brady | Quarterback |

---

My Problem:

- The above code snippet queries and unions two physical tables.

  - My real-world situation involves two computation-intense views.
- Conceptually, I'd like to return the same result set that a `UNION` returns.

  - Except that I don't want to query the second table for rows that already exist in the first table.
- Emphasis: For small tables, this makes no perceptible difference. The SQL Server engine is perfectly capable of filtering out duplicates with the `UNION` clause.

  - But in my real-world situation, I'm not querying two small physical tables. I'm querying two computation-intense views.

Comment: `UNION` itself is notorious for performing badly - changing to `UNION ALL` and excluding rows from the first view might speed things up. Or you could try putting your first query in a CTE and then excluding those results from the query against the second view.

Comment: You might get better performance by first populating working tables with just the keys from each view, deleting using `exists` and having the views use the working table as inputs to a `join` to the source table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some set of keys that are not computation intensive (like id col in your example) I think you best bet would be to use temp table to store results from first view and then union ALL it with second with where check it does not exists in temp table.

```
SELECT * FROM view1
INTO #v1;

SELECT * FROM #v1
UNITON ALL
SELECT * FROM view2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #v1 WHERE #v1.id = view2.id)
```

The second view should perform computations only for missing records.

Using a `WITH` statement can be even better but I'm not sure - that needs to be tested on real data.

```
WITH v1 AS (SELECT * FROM view1)
SELECT * FROM v1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM view2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM v1
  WHERE v1.id = view2.id -- Set duplicate condition here
)
```

Comment: The technical term for `WITH` is a CTE or Common Table Expression :) `with` is just the syntax. Also its quite hit and miss as to whether that will help, because CTEs form 1 large query plan, whereas the temp table solution will be 2 query plans.

Comment: Agree and agree. I simply do not remember cte term but use with when it make sense. I mentioned it might work or not - one of this 2 options should work ok

Comment: I also not 100% sure on syntax as writing from phone